# php session does not work after form submit in php 5.3

Tags: php, session

My code is this. this is a login page. i am creating session after submitting the form. but session is not creating here. but i have created a session at the top just to test, its working. my php version is 5.3+. it was working well before. but the hosting company has a update and the problem begins. all other things are okay.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sessid'] = 123456789;
    print_r($_SESSION);
    include('db_connect.php');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body class="oneColElsCtrHdr">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header"> <a href="index.php?category=all"><img src="main_logo1.png" border="0" alt="logo" height="100" /></a>
        <h2>Celebrating Life Admin Panel</h2>

        <div class="clr"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div id="mainContent">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
    {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
        //$result); die();
        if($result['num'] > 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
        }
        else
            $_SESSION['error'] = "Wrong username or password.";
        mysql_close($conn);
    }
    echo '<h3>Admin Login</h3>';
    if($_SESSION['error']!=""){
        echo '<div class="error">'.$_SESSION['error'].'</div>';
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }
    ?>

    <?php if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']){ $_SESSION['sessidd'] = 123456789564656;?>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
          <table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="margin:0 auto 20px">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Username</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Password</td>
              <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="margin:0 auto 20px">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2" scope="col">
                You have successfully logged in.<br />
                <a href="index.php?category=all">SHOW ALL REGISTRATION DATA</a>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </table>
    <?php } ?>

      </div>
      <div id="footer">

      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: maybe the worst login script I'have seen :D but isnt an error here?: `if($result['num'] > 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
        }
        else { .... }`

Answer (score 1):

you have to register your session with some user data something like

```
              if($result['num'] > 0)
         {
        session_register("id");
        $id = $result['id'];
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = $id;
                 }
```

instead of

```
           if($result['num'] > 0)
         {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
        }
```

hope it will usefull for you